# Decision Tree Coin Toss

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Large decision tree problem.

I have a problem where I think I need to use a decision tree. A coin is being flipped. How many ways can a coin be tossed $10$ times without having $5$ heads in a row?

We know $2^{10} = 1024$. So there will be total possibilities of coin tosses. Is there a way to do this problem without relying on a decision tree?

Comment: "...tossed 10 times without having 5 heads in a row" Exact five heads in a row or can it be even more ?

Comment: Can't be more than that.

Comment: Can it be $HHHHHTTTTH$ ? I mean the 5 heads in a row.

Comment: Yeah, assuming we're given the problem exactly as it was originally worded, I would assume that we are *not* to count HHHHHHTTHH, since it does in fact include five heads in a row.  Conventionally, the sixth consecutive head doesn't put it back into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will try to find how many way that have at least 5 consecutive heads.

We'll first decide where the sequence begin (6 possibilities). The toss immediatly before need, if any, to be tail the rest can be anyting.

If the sequence start with the first toss
$$\left(1\right)^5 \times 2^5 = 32$$
If the sequence start at the $n^{th}$ toss $(1 < n \leq 6)$
$$2^{n-1}\times \left(1\right) \times \left(1\right)^5 \times 2^{5-n}=2^4 = 16$$

So 32 ways if it starts at the beginning, 16 ways if it starts at the second toss, 16 ways if it starts at the third toss $\ldots$
$$32 + 16 + 16 + 16 + 16 + 16 = 112$$

Your answer is $$1024 - 112 = 912$$
There is 912 ways to toss a coin 10 times without having 5 consecutive heads.

Comment: So when you say we start with where the sequence beings, you are saying that at that point we could have already gotten heads 5 times in a row, correct?

Comment: This is where the 5 head start, It is impossible to have 5 heads before this toss.